# How do I add an underline to all section headings in {section in head/foot}?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles, underline

I am using beamer, and I can change the size of the font by using

```
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\scriptsize}
```

However, I do not know the correct way to make this text also underlined. I have attempted to add a style to the template using

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{style=underline},
```

but this just prints "style=underline" instead of all the section headings.

How do I make all of the individual titles underlined?

EDIT: Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Headline Title 1}
\begin{frame}{Local Title 1}
\end{frame}
 \section{Headline Title 2}
\begin{frame}{Local Title 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What theme are you using? In fact, can you create a complete, *minimal* example that replicates your current setup? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're currently seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: I added it to the first post. I want to be able to add an underline to {section in head/foot} but I can't figure out the right syntax for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section header that is inserted is constructed as the sections/frames are set. So one would have to intervene during the setting of the header. Knowing that `\insertsectionhead` prints `\hyperlink{<target>}{<title>}`, you can redefine `\hyperlink` to insert `\hyperlink{<target>}{\underline{<title>}}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \let\oldhyperlink\hyperlink% Store old \hyperlink
    %  Update \hyperlink to insert \underline around second ##2 argument
    \renewcommand{\hyperlink}[2]{\oldhyperlink{##1}{\underline{##2}}}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Headline Title 1}
\begin{frame}{Local Title 1}
\end{frame}
 \section{Headline Title 2}
\begin{frame}{Local Title 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You may want to use

```
\renewcommand{\hyperlink}[2]{\oldhyperlink{##1}{\underline{\smash{##2}}}}%
```

instead, as header titles with descenders might cause vertical nonalignment of the `\underline`.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer.