# headline in Beamer: What is the syntax to add a second, static box above my current custom headline?

Tags: beamer, xetex, templates, headline

I have a custom headline that puts the titles of all frames into a navigation bar at the top of all slides. It is this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \let\oldhyperlink\hyperlink
    \renewcommand{\hyperlink}[2]{\oldhyperlink{##1}{\underline{\smash{##2}}}}
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
```

What I want to do is put a second, static bar of text above this bar. It will not have any dynamic information and be the same on all slides. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: You are aware that the answers on tex.se are licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0? This in particular means, you should include a link back to @Werner's answer, from which you have the code for the underlining from.

Comment: I have never heard of him or seen his code. Thanks.

Comment: The code seems to come from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630148/36296

Answer (score 1):

You could place your static text in another `beamercolorbox` above it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot} Some static text
    \end{beamercolorbox}
   }%
   
   \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \let\oldhyperlink\hyperlink
    \renewcommand{\hyperlink}[2]{\oldhyperlink{##1}{\underline{\smash{##2}}}}
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}


\begin{document}
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]